# FInd Defined Range cells name

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have multiple Defined Range Cell in Sheet1

```
    A          B
1   Person 1   Person 2
2   Vp-1       Sf-1
3   Vp-2       Sf-2
4   Vp-3       Sf-3
5   VP-4       Sf-4
6
7   Person 3   Person 4
8   Op-1       Zc-1
9   Op-2       Zc-2
10  Op-3       Zc-3
11  OP-4       Zc-4
```

Range number 1, named 'Person 1' (A1:A5), and 'Person2' (B1:B5)

in Sheet2,

```
    A            B          C          D
1   PERSON       Value 1    Value 2    Value 3
2   Person 1     Vp-1       Vp-2       Vp-3
3   Person 2     Sf-1       Sf-2       Sf-3
4   Person 3     Of-1       Of-2       Of-3
5   Person 4     Zc-1       Zc-2       Zc-3
```

I need to return the value "Vp-1" by look-up "Person 1" (A2) in defined range name in sheet 1, and return its first value in the range.

Comment: What makes Vp-3 special? Are you trying to return the third value in the Person1 named range? Are you trying to return the value ion Person1 that corresponds to Sf-3 in Person2? Your narrative is too ambiguous to provide an answer.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your **actual** range name?  `Person 1` is not a legal name (names cannot include spaces).  I suggest you look at the `INDIRECT` function to find your named range.  Then you can do a simple lookup.  Post back with your efforts and any problems (edit your original post).